# How to preserve data in recursions with iterations

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to code a solution for Linear [Peg Solitaire Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peg_solitaire).

By linear, I mean that the board is a single dimensional array with 1 hole in it. And pieces only either move for left to right or right to left.

I'm trying to calculate the best possible solution. Where either there are no more moves left or there is a single peg left.

So, I pass the board to a recursive function, In the function I calculate all the `legalMoves` and make them one after the other untill there are no more moves left. Once a sub tree is completed I want to do the same for the next tree and so on untill all the solutions are calculated.

Here is a sample of code that I wrote up.

```
public static int makeMove(int[] board, ArrayList<MoveSet> moves) {
    int pegCount = getPegCount(board);

    if (pegCount < bestCount) {
        bestMoves = moves;
        bestCount = pegCount;
    }

    ArrayList<MoveSet> legalMoves = getLegalMoves(board);
    printMoves(legalMoves);

    if (pegCount == 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (legalMoves.size() == 0) {
        return pegCount;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < legalMoves.size(); ++i) {
        MoveSet move = legalMoves.get(i);
        moves.add(move);
        board = movePeg(board, move); // board is manipulated
        makeMove(board, moves);
    }
    System.out.println("===============");
    return pegCount;
}
```

The problem with this code is that, once a sub tree is completed. The next subtree is based on the manipulated board not the original board which the moves are to be made on.

```
For example : 

Length of board : 5
Hole is on index : 2

Board : 1 1 0 1 1
Legal Moves are from index 2-3-4 or 0-1-2(This is executed later)
If I make the move 2-3-4
Board : 1 1 1 0 0 
Legal Moves : 1-2-3
Board : 1 0 0 1 0
No More Legal Moves!

Moving to the next sub-tree
0-1-2
Board : 1 0 0 1 0 //This should be 1 1 0 1 1 not 1 0 0 1 0
```

How do I maintain the state of the board when making the next move.

Here's the whole code if anyone is interested in looking at it.

http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/c6lOb6

Comment: Why not make the move on a copy of the board and pass that on?

Comment: You need to backtrack, which means to undo the changes when returning from the recursion, i.e. after `makeMove()`, call `moves.remove(moves.size() - 1)`. If `movePeg()` truly returns an updated copy *(why else have a return value)*, then you don't need to undo the board itself.

Comment: Without studying your code closely: In a backtracking solution like the one I believe you are building, there are two or three standard options: (1) reverse the move after you have tried it so the board gets back to the state from before doing that move and the subtree under it (2) take a copy of the board before making the move so the original board is untouched (2b) instead of a full copy, invent some representaion of changes made to a given board that you can stack up as the tree grows deeper; probably the most complicated solution.

Comment: @Andreas & Ole Thank you for your inputs. I understood what went wrong. I'll write up a method to back track the moves that are made before a sub-tree is solved.